# Skipping a parametrized combination

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

i'm writing a test in python2.7 and the test method receives two parameters.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("letter", [
    "A", "B", "C"])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", [
    1, 2, 3])
def my_test(letter, number):
    if letter == "B" and number == 2:
        pytest.skip("redundant")
```

I need to skip a redundant combination, let's say for example (B, 2). The only "working" solution leads to calling setup_methods which is useless. Is there a more elegant solution to skip the combination without writing additional "if" condition and without accessing setup_method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "redundant"?

Comment: I mean for example that (B, 2) is useless to test because it's gonna fail. I need to skip it since a test run takes 15 minutes and requires lots of resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I would see other than your solution is to write down all possible combinations yourself and comment out or remove all redundant ones (this may be a bit more explicit):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("letter,number", [
    ("A", 1),
    ("A", 2),
    ("A", 3),
    ("B", 1),
    # ("B", 2),
    ("B", 3),
    ("C", 1),
    ("C", 2),
    ("C", 3),
])
def test_foo(letter, number):
    assert something...
```

This way you save yourself the if, but I like your solution in that way that pytest produces a nice output where it tells you which / that a combination was skipped:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 9 items

stackoverflow.py::test[1-A] PASSED                                       [ 11%]
stackoverflow.py::test[1-B] PASSED                                       [ 22%]
stackoverflow.py::test[1-C] PASSED                                       [ 33%]
stackoverflow.py::test[2-A] PASSED                                       [ 44%]
stackoverflow.py::test[2-B] SKIPPED                                      [ 55%]
Skipped: redundant

stackoverflow.py::test[2-C] PASSED                                       [ 66%]
stackoverflow.py::test[3-A] PASSED                                       [ 77%]
stackoverflow.py::test[3-B] PASSED                                       [ 88%]
stackoverflow.py::test[3-C] PASSED                                       [100%]

========================= 8 passed, 1 skipped in 0.07s =========================
```

I guess in this case it's a subjective decision. Both options bear their benefits and downsides.